# Edit MongoDB Stores for Output

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to manipulate some Data from MongoDB Container before returning it. The problem I can´t solve is the change of data type. The "deviceClass" is a number and I want to change it to a string without success. Is there a way to save the mongodb store in a variable that accepts cross type editing of the array?

Thanks for our help

input:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "XXX",
        [...]
        "deviceClass": 1,
        [...]
    },
    [...]
]
```

```
app.get('/api/v1/device',  isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Device.find(

      { userId: req.user._id, },
      []

    ).exec(function (err, device) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);

      if (device) {
        var updateArray = {};
        updateArray = device;        
        for(let i = 0; i< updateArray.length; i++){
          console.log("deviceClass: " + updateArray[i].deviceClass); //deviceClass is 0
          updateArray[i].deviceClass = "test";
          console.log("deviceClass: " + updateArray[i].deviceClass); //deviceClass is still 0

        }
        return res.json(updateArray);

      } else {
        return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg: 'No devices.'});
      }

    });
  });
```

deviceClass should change to the String "test" in this case before returned

Console Output here is:

deviceClass: 1

deviceClass: 1

Comment: What does your `Device` schema look like, assuming you're using Mongoose.js

Comment: This is the schema: https://pastebin.com/H2qmuihb

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the function bind syntax to return a modified value instead of what is actually stored in the database.
eg:

```
return res.json({
    ...device._doc,
    deviceClass: updateClass.bind(this, device.deviceClass)
});

const updateClass = oldClass => {
    // ...
}
```

and in the updateClass method you can put the logic to modify the data however you like. This will return the value returned by the updateClass function and not the value stored in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your `deviceClass` to a `String`, you can change your `deviceClass` type to `Mixed` in your Schema.  Then you can update like so:

`updateArray[i].deviceClass = new String("test");`

and then save the document.